# Solving $F(x)=0$ in the unit ball, using homotopy arguments

Tags: real-analysis, homotopy-theory

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^k\backslash \{0\},$ we set $\psi:= \phi/ |\phi| : \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{S}^{k-1}.$ The claim, is that for every smooth extension $F$ of $\phi$ insider the unit $n-$ ball, there exists a zero of $F,$ (i.e. a point $x$ such that $F(x) = 0$) if and only if $\psi$ is homotopically nontrivial.

Here's an attempt. let $F$ be a smooth extension of $\phi$ inside the unit ball, such that $F(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$ in the unit ball. Then, one notes that 
$G: \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{S}^{k-1}$ given by $G(x,t) = F(tx)/|F(tx)|,$ yields a homotopy between $\psi$ and a constant.

How does one show the converse?

Comment: Hint:  Suppose you have a homotopy between $\psi$ and a constant.  Well, a homotopy has domain $S^{n-1}\times [0,1]$.  Think about this domain in the context of polar coordinates...

Comment: @Raghav I want to clarify a question: did the problem equals that **there exists a function $F$ which satisfies $F(x)\not=0$, for any $x\in\mathbb B^n$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\psi$ is homotopocial to a constant?**

Comment: The problem is as is stated: Namely, that $\psi$ is homotopic to a constant if and only if there exists an extension $F$ of $\phi$ inside the unit ball that has no zero there.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H:\mathbb S^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb S^{k-1}$ be homotopy map between $\phi$ and a constant $\frac{\phi(0)}{|\phi(0)|}$.

We construct $F:\mathbb D^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^k-\{0\}$ which satisfies

> $$
> F(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> |\phi(x)|H(\frac{x}{|x|},|x|)~~~~~~~~~~x\in\mathbb D^n\\
> \phi(0)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x=0
> \end{cases}
> $$

Then proof is complete.